# Google maps GeoLocation API key isn't linking to my Google Developer account

Tags: google-maps

I've looked everywhere to a solution for this, and I guess I've missed something obvious:
My web application (Civicrm 4.6.17) allows me to insert a Google GeoLocation API key for it's mapping and GeoLocation services. I've gone through the process described by [Google GeoCoding Developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro):

1. setup a project,
2. [got an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key),
3. Linked that key to my domain(s)
4. Even enabled billing for Pay as you go in case of over-limits.

Each step appeared to be successful. We have a project, we have an API key, we have billing enabled for it... all of this is reflected in the Google developer's console.

However, while we are processing 100s of GeoLocation requests per day, none are appearing in my project's Quota information. And we are hitting the 2,500 complementary limit.

What can I do to find out why the API key isn't linking to our Project?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go on the Stack Exchange Webmasters site.

Comment: Can you show an example of your HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

While the Google API has an unauthenticated limit of 2,500 requests per day per IP, using an API key currently gives a quota of 100,000 requests per day.

CiviCRM was not using the API key, but I've just opened an issue to address that here: [CRM-18830: Google Geocoding - use SSL, restore API key](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18830).

Once that fix is merged (assuming it is), you should be able to geocode a larger number of addresses.